# Updating a Sub-component in a Variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, split

I am trying to update data inside a variable with Powershell. I can retrieve the data I need out of the variable but I am unable to update only a single field inside the variable.

I can update an entire line by using `$HL7data[0] = 'foo'` but I don't know how to change just a single field within a line, i.e. when delimited by `|` and `^`.

The main issue as I see it is that it becomes string data and I am no longer working inside a variable.

I have tried find and replace on the string I output. This has worked for unique values, but values such as suburbs might exist several times in the data and all get replaced.

I have also tried splitting the data into a multidimensional array, but I don't know to store the result as an array and split it further, and I also don't know how to join all the data again as each layer uses a different delimiter.

Ideally, I'd like to drill down into the data by delimiter (newline, `|`, `^`, etc.) and position, change the value retrieved, and save it back into the original structure.

This is the code I've tried:

```bsh
$HL7data = get-content("5a0a7726672afLOE_1802.hl7")

(((($HL7data[0] -split("\|"))[11])-split("\^"))[2]) = 'Not Jingili"
```

This is the test data (inside `5a0a7726672afLOE_1802.hl7`) which is two lines:

```
PID|||^^^AUSHIC^MC||Lname^Fname^^^Mr||||||123 Test Street^^Jingili^NT^0881||^PRN^PH^^^^|^WPN^PH^^^^|
OBR||||GRF^FileName||20171114124758|
```

The suburb `Jingili` should change to `Not Jingili` in the complete data. The code I've tried does not change the contents of the variable `$HL7data`.

I've also just tried the following code to break down the steps:

```bsh
$ary1 = @()
foreach ($line in $HL7data)
{
    $ary2 = @()
    foreach ($Seg in $line-split("\|"))
    {
        $ary3 = @()
        foreach ($item in $seg-split("\^"))
        {
            $ary3 += $item
        }
        $ary2 += $ary3
    }
    $ary1 += $ary2
}
$ary1[0][11][2] = "Not Jingili"
```

The last line `$ary1[0][11][2] = "Not Jingili"` doesn't work. It gives an error:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:19 char:1
+ $ary1[0][11][2] = "Not Jingili"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

If it had worked, I would have then recombined the nested arrays back into a text data structure.

Comment: Should all suburbs `^Jingili^` be replaced with `^Not Jingili^` or is there a condition to that?

Comment: No, only the single instance. at that location `[0][11][2]`, Typically there is a send and receive address (In rare cases can be the same suburb), as well as the suburb, is often used in the building name such as "North Jingili IT."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
# Read data from file
$file = Get-Content "5a0a7726672afLOE_1802.hl7"

# Split data into a multidimensional array
$segments = @()
foreach ($line in $file)
{
  $fields = @()
  foreach ($field in $line -split "\|")
  {
    $fields += ,@($field -split "\^")
  }
  $segments += ,@($fields)
}

# Change as many values as you want here
$segments[0][11][0] = "1 Test Ave"
$segments[0][11][2] = "Not Jingili"

# Join data into a single flat array
$flat_segments = @()
foreach ($fields in $segments)
{
  $flat_fields = @()
  foreach ($field in $fields)
  {
    $flat_fields += $field -join "^"
  }
  $flat_segments += $flat_fields -join "|"
}

# Dump changed data
$flat_segments
```

**Note:** I see you are working with HL7 data. Each line in the new file should end with `\r` (`0x0D`), not `\n` (`0x0A`) or `\r\n` (`0x0D`,`0x0A`). Powershell doesn't care what line endings the input file is using and will discard them.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is the `-Replace` param. I am unsure why you have `$HL7data[0]` unless `$HL7data` is a collection of some kind.

```
$HL7data = $HL7data -replace "$(((($HL7data -split("\|"))[11])-split("\^"))[2])","Not Jingili"
```

`$HL7data =` will overwrite the initial variable with what ever follows.

`$HL7data -replace "FIND AUSSIE SUBURB","REPLACE AUSSIE SUBURB"`

Adding a `$` in front of your search string encased in `"` will allow the expansion of variables as well as the use of the `"` within the expression.

Comment: The code has inserted `Not Jingili` between all the characters in the original data. The data now consists almost entirely of `Not Jingili`. Also, there could be multiple instances of `Jingili` in the data and I only want to replace a specific instance.

Comment: Which is why I noted the `[0]` section in the code. You must have a collection and only wanted to change the first one. Your question is too broad and did not advise that you have a collection other than the inclusion of `[0]`. Just add the `[0]` to both of the `$HL7Data` and you're good to change the first line.

Comment: I understand where the confusion came from, I have updated the question.

Comment: `$HL7data = $HL7data -replace "$(((($HL7data[0] -split("\|"))[11])-split("\^"))[2])","Not Jingili"` Does work to replace the data correctly But It replaces ALL "Jingili" rather then just the target Jingili.

Comment: @Maylife why not just use `$HL7data[0] = $HL7data[0] -replace "$(((($HL7data[0] -split("\|"))[11])-split("\^"))[2])","Not Jingili"` then?

Comment: @AdminOfThings Interesting, That definitely does decrease the risk of overwriting the wrong data as each line should only contain a single address. Ideally, I would like to go a layer deeper to further decrease the risk. But yes that does work correctly and has only overwritten the Targert `"Jingili"